# How do I receive a JSON response after calling knockoutjs postJson?

Tags: jquery, json, knockout.js

When I call knockoutjs postJson() function, is there any way to call a function on a successful Json response from the server like you can with Jquery's ajax post?

I want to do either of 2 things:

1) PostJson and then have the controller respond with a Json error message if the validation fails.

2) Model validation succeeds and the page is postedback (using RedirectToAction('Index')).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ko.utils.postJson is intended to post data to the server as though you did a submit for your form and will post the JSON as urlencoded data.  If you want to post data via AJAX and run code on success or failure, then your best bet is to use the jQuery AJAX functions.  Also, you can use ko.toJSON(yourobject) to conveniently get a JSON representation of your object with all observables unwrapped properly.

Something like:

```
$.ajax({
    url: yourcontroller/action,
    type: "POST",
    data: ko.toJSON(yourdata),
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function(data) {
       ...do something
    }
});
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused, I've been using ko.toJS(this); and then use [FromJson] attribute on the server-side.  How does this relate to the ajax post-back and your Json example?  I'm not sure of the difference between toJS and toJSON.

Comment: If you do it this way (AJAX post), you will not need to create or use the [FromJson] attribute from Steve's example to deserialize it.  MVC 3 has this functionality built-in.  ko.toJS turns your view model into a javascript object with all observables unwrapped.  ko.toJSON does the same, but then converts the object to JSON, which is the string representation that is transferred to the server.

Answer (score 3):

You can also make your own handy postJson() function if you plan on posting json in more than one place.

```
$.postJson = function (url, data, callback) {
    return jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: url,
        data: ko.toJSON(data),
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json'
    }).success(callback).error(function (jqhr, text) { alert(text); });
}
```

And you would then use it as such:

```
$.postJson("some/url", {some:"data"}, function(response) {
    // do something with the response
});
```